# SSD firmware update problem

Tags: ssd, firmware

I'm on Pop OS 22.04 LTS. Recently I got a problem saying

> systend-journald (...) Failed to write entry ...

(I don't remember what exactly the ...-s said)

However, I got an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173738/crash-systemd-journal-failed-to-write-entry-ignoring-read-only-file-system-on

But my intel SSD isn't in a supported format in the listed SSDs in intel firmware update site.
Also, I tried to update firmware using `fwupd` as the instructions on [this site](https://linoxide.com/how-to-update-firmware-on-ubuntu-using-fwupd/). But it said no updates available.
Also, the laptop shuts down often, and if tried to boot, says `no bootable device found.`
However, after some times, it boots without any problem.

How to solve this?

Comment: I don't think a firmware update solves this if there is no firmware updates available! You're confusing "one possible problem is this: XYZ and it can be solved by updating your firmware" with "every problem is solved by updating your firmware".